# Suricata IDS: No logs in /var/log/suricata

Tags: security, logging

I recently installed Suricate (3.0) on Linux Ubuntu 16.04LTS, however after configuring the `/etc/suricata/suricata-debian.yaml` file and starting the service, no logs could be found in `/var/log/suricata`. 
I re-checked the .yaml configuration file and found that the `/var/log/suricata` route was configured for logging, and that (most) logs were enabled, yet no logs in that directory route exist.

Im not sure why, and I have not found anyone else suffering this problem on the Internet.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

The problem did not reside in any of the logging-configuration in the Suricata config-file. Instead, Suricata was scrutinizing the wrong interface and therefor had no data to process, and therefor no logs.

Buried in the Suricata configuration file, there is reference to certain interfaces, this was solved by rearranging it to direct Suricata's IDS functionality towards the correct interface.

I am plaguing the Internet with my own idiocy.